# Some styles not rendered in the browser with sass --style compressed

Tags: css, sass

I refactored some vanilla CSS by renaming individual .css files as .scss and `@import`ing them into one master file. The contents of that file looks like this:

```
@import file1
@import file2
@import file3
```

In the same directory, lives `_file1.scss`, `_file2.scss`, `_file3.scss`.

Everything works, but for some reason, when I add the flag `--style compressed` the minified output is missing classes, etc. It also works fine with `--style compact` so whatever is going wrong is specific to compressed.

I'm on OSX 10.9.2, with Sass v3.2.10 (Media Mark). I'm using the following command:

```
sass --watch style.style.min.css --style compressed
```

When I do NOT minify the output (by removing `--style compressed`) the resulting CSS works fine.

Any ideas what could be going wrong?

**Specific code:**
I can't post the whole file but here's a sample with the code that's not working...

.scss

```
/*!XXXXXXXXXX*/
/* route colors */
.subway_metrorail_red       { background:#e45340; color:#fff; }
.subway_metrorail_orange    { background:#efaa49; color:#fff; }
.subway_metrorail_yellow    { background:#7a7a17; color:#fff; }
.subway_metrorail_green     { background:#52b05f; color:#fff; }
.subway_metrorail_blue      { background:#3f8cda; color:#fff; }
```

(minified) .css

```
... .subway_metrorail_blue h3{color:#000}/*!XXXXXXXXXX*/.subway_metrorail_red{background:#e45340;color:#fff}.subway_metrorail_orange{background:#efaa49;color:#fff} ...
```

**UPDATE:**
I'm starting to think this has nothing to do with sass compiling the CSS... If I take the exact same code that results from `--compact` and add one line break or two, the styles get applied normally. Is there a maximum line length for CSS files or something?

**UPDATE2:**

The validator doesn't like this:

```
.car2go_icon {
    background-image:url("../images/car2go_logo_50.png");
    background-size: 158px 50px;
    background-position: 0px 20px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
    src='../../../public/images/car2go_logo_50.png',
    sizingMethod='crop')";
}
```

**UPDATE 3:**
I think the line breaks within the string after `-ms-filter:` are the problem! They fail validation when I leave the code as you see it above. But when I remove the line breaks they seem to pass. I have a feeling that this is breaking during magnification. Does anyone know more about the correct syntax for -ms-filter than me?

Comment: Please provide enough example .sass code so that we can see the problem; the .sass which has the classes that are missing?

Comment: @KatieK I added an example of the code that is not working when minified.

Comment: After the edit, I am still not sure what is missing. Is it definitions for `subway_metrorail_yellow` through to `subway_metrorail_blue` entirely?

Comment: @halfer Sorry let me clarify. No styles go "missing". Rather, the browser just stops recognizing them. I can find them in the source code, but when I use the developer tools, they are not being applied.

Comment: Ah right. What browser are you trying? Is it the same across various browsers? Are there any browser console warnings about the bad version of the CSS, e.g. in Firefox?

Comment: I've clarified the title, but you may wish to change "the minified output is missing classes" - I can't see how that means anything other than something is absent in the generated CSS output.

Comment: @halfer The problem happens in all browsers I've tried: Safari, FF, Chrome

Comment: Duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757665/sass-color-variable-hex-output

Comment: @cimmanon This question has nothing to do with that.

Answer (score -1):

This may not working because number of css lines exceeding 4000+. If you try to put some of your sass in another files and make each file under 4000 lines I think that will work for you.

Comment: This would only be true if we were talking about IE.