# SASS HEX to RGB without 'rgb' prefix

Tags: sass, material-design, material-design-lite

**The Question:**

Is there a SASS function/technique that transforms a HEX value to a *simple* RGB string.

Simple here meaning just a string without it being enclosed in `rgb()`  ?

E.g: `#D50000 --> "213,0,0"`

---

**Why I need this:**

I'm using [Material Design Lite](http://getmdl.io) as my UI 'framework'. More specifically I'm using the SASS version so I can tweak the color variables according to my app's style-guide.

For some reason the color variables in `_variables.scss` of MDL take this format for color definitions:

```
$color-primary: "0,0,0" !default; // supposed to be black
```

which is really, really odd. I expected, *at most*, something along the lines of

```
$color-primary: rgba(0,0,0,1) !default;
```

My color variables are stored in another file called `_globals.scss` in which I store my variables in regular HEX format so I can easily reuse them in other places:

```
$brand-primary: #FA3166;
$brand-primary-dark: #E02C59;
```

I don't want to define 2 times my colours (1 HEX & 1 MDL-compatible RGB string), hence the reason I need to transform HEX to RGB-string.

Comment: You should consider not using such a crappy library.  This is a horrible anti-pattern.  Google should be ashamed for writing this.

Comment: Did you use it extensively? Or are you judging based on this aspect of it? I'm asking because I (want) to believe that I'm just following the wrong approach to customising the palette

Comment: I looked through the source.  No one in their right mind would handle colors like this.  What they're doing is akin to using strings for handling currency.

Comment: @cimmanon I'm thinking that there is a reason for that, actually, and the case is that I'm missing the proper route to define colours. I've opened a Github Issue [here](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/1689) asking the same

Comment: The only reason to do this would be to force it to output in the RGB format (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757665/why-does-sass-change-the-format-of-my-colors).  This just happens to be an exceptionally terrible way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've hacked around it with a SASS function:

```
@function hexToString($hexColor) {

  // 0.999999 val in alpha actually compiles to 1.0
  $rgbaVal: inspect(rgba($hexColor,0.9999999));

  // slice substring between 'rgba(' and '1.0)' 
  @return str-slice($rgbaVal, 6, str-length($rgbaVal)-6);

}
```

Usage:

```
$brand-primary: #333;
$color-primary: hexToString($brand-primary);
```

---

I think the MDL team intended to have a different way to customise the palette and I'm missing it, so if someone knows a better way to customise MDL's palette I'm open to suggestions. Either way this solves the original question.

Comment: I wonder if there is a less hacky way than using the 0.99999 alpha val. in the `rgba()` function. I have a case where I explicitly need an rgb or rgba value, because inline svg chokes on an unescaped '#' character.

Answer (score 9):

@nicholas-kyriakides's answer works perfectly fine, but here is a more concise function using Sass interpolation.

```
@function hexToRGBString($hexColor) {
  @return "#{red($hexColor)},#{green($hexColor)},#{blue($hexColor)}";
}
```

You can pass in either a hex either explicity or from rgb() or rgba() with opacity as 1.

For example:

```
$color-white: hexToRGBString(#fff) => "255,255,255"
$color-white: hexToRGBString(rgb(255,255,255)) => "255,255,255"
$color-white: hexToRGBString(rgba(#fff,1)) => "255,255,255"
```

Comment: Note that you may need to add `round` to avoid having invalid values in your `rgb()` if you are modifying your hex values with for example `lighten` or `darken`. For example:

`@return "#{round(red($hexColor))},#{round(green($hexColor))},#{round(blue($hexColor))}";`

Answer (score 2):

For anyone that is using Bootstrap and runs across this question, they have a built-in function that does this.

```scss
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";

$brand-primary: #333;
$color-primary: to-rgb($brand-primary);
```

If you dig into [the source for this](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/scss/_functions.scss#L36-L38), it's simple:

```scss
@function to-rgb($value) {
  @return red($value), green($value), blue($value);
}
```