# How to convert named color to HEX using SCSS?

Tags: sass

I have a mixin with named colors:

```
@mixin color-classes-rendering {
    $colors: (
        rebeccapurple
    );

    @each $value in $colors {
        .#{nw}-#{nth($value, 1)}#{" > span"} {
            background-color: nth($value, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is compiled CSS:

```
.nw-rebeccapurple > span {
    background-color: rebeccapurple;
}
```

I don't know why, but "rebeccapurple" doesn't shown in Chrome at Android.
Is it possible to convert it to this one:

```
.nw-rebeccapurple > span {
    background-color: #663399;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

While Sass does provide functions to extract the individual R, G, and B values for any given color, it doesn't provide a convenient way to convert those to hexadecimal.  It would be simpler for you to convert it to the rgb() format.

```
$color: rebeccapurple;

.foo {
    color: #{'rgb(#{red($color)}, #{green($color)}, #{blue($color)})'};
}
```

Output:

```
.foo {
  color: rgb(102, 51, 153);
}
```

See also: [Why does Sass change the format of my colors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757665/why-does-sass-change-the-format-of-my-colors)

---

I should also point out that what you've written so far would be better suited to a mapping:

```
$colors: (
    'rebeccapurple': #639,
    'black': #000
);

@each $name, $color in $colors {
    .nw-#{$name} > span {
        background-color: $color;
    }
}
```

Output (compressed format):

```
.nw-rebeccapurple > span { background-color: #639; }

.nw-black > span { background-color: #000; }
```

Comment: It works if I point the value of color in variable, but how can I implement it in map?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  You do while looping over the mapping the same way you would with the variable.

Comment: I mean, what if I don't want to put this named color into variables, and just want to use them in a map? In my case, I have a list with about 10 colors and don't want to use variables for each of them.

Comment: And?  You don't have to put them into a variable.  You can replace `$color` with rebeccapurple directly.  Or write a function to do it.

Comment: OK, nice idea, I like it =) I will try.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to put the HEX value of each named color manually, like this:

```
@mixin color-classes-rendering {
    $colors: (
        rebeccapurple   #663399,
        black           #000000
    );

    @each $value in $colors {
        .#{nw}-#{nth($value, 1)}#{" > span"} {
            background-color: nth($value, 2);
        }
    }
}
```