# How can I configure the format for the value for Sass variables, during the conversion to CSS?

Tags: sass

Me and my team are using Sass (through ***grunt-contrib-sass***) to build our stylesheets. However, when we commit to Git, we found certain differences to the CSS that's being generated among our team members. 
When storing a color in a variable, and applying it to a class, we have two different outputs:

Output 1:

```
outline: #90B2E9 solid 1px;
```

Output 2:

```
outline: #90b2e9 solid 1px;
```

Output 1:

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #A6C9DB 100%);
```

Output 2:

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, white 0%, #a6c9db 100%);
```

As you an see, one machine generates Hex codes in lower case, other in upper case. One generates Hex code, one the color alias.

Is there a way configure Sass to always format color codes the same way, for all out machines?

Comment: Are you certain every developer is using the same version of Sass?  And those are definitely the same lines of code, not 2 similar looking lines of code where one author has used capitalization and one author didn't (because Sass preserves case: http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/2494591707200e0ca5d0)?  See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757665/why-does-sass-change-the-format-of-my-colors/15763085

Comment: As @cimmanon pointed out, I'd also check whether you all have the same version of softwares installed. I assume you installed *grunt-contrib-sass* via *npm* and that your _node_modules_ folder is listed in your *.gitignore* file. Try browsing to the folder where you have your *package.json* file and run the `npm install --force` command on every machine and see if that fixes the issue.