# Exclude color property from sass compilation

Tags: colors, properties, webpack, compilation, sass

Is there a way to exclude color propertys from sass compilation in webpack sass compiler, to prevent the opacity problem in child elements. 
At the moment it compile this:

```
div {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
```

to:

```
div {
  background: white;
}
```

Sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: This may point you to the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757665/why-does-sass-change-the-format-of-my-colors

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent it. Because it's a sass function that converts the color to hex.

But there are few ways to avoid it

1. you can create your own rgba function that will do the trick for you

   `@function rgba($r, $g, $b, $a) {
         @return unquote('rgba(#{$r}, #{$g}, #{$b}, #{$a})');
    }`

But doing this means there are changes that, if some one is using `rgba(hex, a)` then it will fail, if there are some one using syntax like `rgba(rgb(255,255,255), 1)` then also it will fail. So you have to look in your project structure and see how the syntax is there in all the files. And you have to mention to the team to use rgba alone.

2. Or else you can create a simple mixin

   `@mixin mysuper-rgba($hexcolor, $opacity) {
   background-color: $hexcolor;
   background-color: rgba($hexcolor, $opacity);
   }

   body {
    @include mysuper-rgba(#11111, 0.5);
   }`

What I suggest is create a mixin that will do the trick for you and ask all your developers to use the same.