# Scss - Why is rgba being converted to hsla

Tags: css, sass

I'm using web pack to compile my scss files to css, I'm also using Bootstrap 4 for my project.

I noticed something odd, in my scss file I have the following property:

```
color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
```

After web pack has done compiling, in the output css, it is being converted to:

```
color: hsla(0,0%,100%,.5);
```

However I don't want this to happen, how can I prevent this conversion from rgba to hsla from taking place?

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757665/why-does-sass-change-the-format-of-my-colors

Comment: And: https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/469

Comment: This guy [had same problem](https://github.com/shama/stylus-loader/issues/196).

Answer (score 0):

sertting **colormin** option to false for **cssnano** pugin inside **postcss-loader** fixed this issue for me:

```
plugins: [ 
    require('cssnano')({
        colormin: false,
    })
]
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was with **postcss-color-converter**.

It converted som hex colors to rgb and others to hsla, seemingly very inconsistently. It also converted some rgb colors to hsla.

I removed this:

```
require("postcss-color-converter")({ outputColorFormat: "rgb" })
```

from

> postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require("autoprefixer"),
    require("cssnano")({ preset: "default" }),
    require("postcss-color-converter")({ outputColorFormat: "rgb" }),
  ],
}
```

Like so:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require("autoprefixer"),
    require("cssnano")({ preset: "default" }),
  ],
}
```